# Microcontroller driven motor driver has a delayed response time?

Tags: motordriver

I am wondering if changing the motor driver can lead to a faster response of the DC motors in my robot.

I am using an Arduino Mega which is connected to a BTS7960B motor driver. The robot takes about 50 to 100 milliseconds delay time to respond to sensor's inputs and I am confident that it is not a programming issue.

The motors are not very high power, 12V in for 1000 rpm and a stall current of 5.9A. I am using four motors, two on each side of the robot connected in parallel.

Will changing the motor driver help to increase the reaction speed of my robot?

In addition does anyone have any advice to allow the robot to react quickly while its moving at a high speed.

Hope my description is enough. I can provide further information if needed.

Comment: Try formatting your sentences to make reading this wall of text much easier. Capitalization of words at the start of a sentence is also nice to do if you want people to take you seriously and bother to make an answer. The period (.) is also used at the end of sentences and I see none except here: 7.5 and here: 5.9.

Comment: Use an oscilloscope to compare the motor response to the micro output. There's no point in guessing when you can test.

Comment: We don't expect every post to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your post to improve it. This is site policy. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Answer (score 0):

[Datasheet of motor driver](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/bts7960b-pb-final.pdf?folderId=db3a3043156fd5730116144c5d101c30&fileId=db3a30431ed1d7b2011efe782ebd6b60)

I cant help but notice there are a lot of safety controls in your driver. It is possible that the current limitation is not set up right, meaning your motor may take longer than expected to start,

How slow "digitalWrite" is compared to hard registers is ruled out by the time scale, I would still suspect your code, so the easiest way to test it would be make the input something you directly control for a test, e.g. a push button, the moment the Arduino sees it change, it turns on or off the motor, this can remove your code from the equation.

Edit: As to making the robot react while in motion, the usual approach would be to have the H-bridges driven off PWM pins, this way the micro is free to process, rather than having to look after toggling the pins.

Edit2: I now see motors in parallel not drivers in parallel, I still am suspecting you may have the current limits incorrectly set up.

Comment: I see that my post was not cleanly readable ,maybe because I am not a native speaker,but as I said I tried out to run a simple code and test the reaction ,even without PWM,but no improvement. Also I don't have an access to an oscilloscope,but I was confused to figure out that there is a motor driver "zerolag" from jsumo which says that it has no delay,btw I connected the 2 dc motrs to the same h-bridge in parallel because they are supposed to run at the same direction and speed.I hope you have understood me...and thanks.